# redis freeReplyObject not freeing memory

Tags: c, valgrind, hiredis

Here is the code:

```
redisReply * reply;
char * stats = get_key(key, reply);
freeReplyObject( reply );
```

`get_key` is a function in a separate header file:

```
char * get_key(const char* key, redisReply * reply)
{
    reply = redisCommand(rc, "GET %s", key);
    if (reply->type != REDIS_REPLY_ERROR) {
        return reply->str;
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

and Valgrind says this about it:

```
==24846== 2,592 bytes in 54 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 63 of 85
==24846==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24846==    by 0x4E3E342: createReplyObject (hiredis.c:64)
==24846==    by 0x4E3E342: createNilObject (hiredis.c:179)
==24846==    by 0x4E469FE: processBulkItem (read.c:267)
==24846==    by 0x4E469FE: processItem (read.c:407)
==24846==    by 0x4E469FE: redisReaderGetReply (read.c:503)
==24846==    by 0x4E406E3: redisGetReplyFromReader (hiredis.c:863)
==24846==    by 0x4E407CA: redisGetReply (hiredis.c:890)
==24846==    by 0x409DEE: RedisCluster::HiredisCommand<RedisCluster::Cluster<redisContext, RedisCluster::DefaultContainer<redisContext> > >::processHiredisCommand(redisContext*) (in /bucket)
==24846==    by 0x408E3A: RedisCluster::HiredisCommand<RedisCluster::Cluster<redisContext, RedisCluster::DefaultContainer<redisContext> > >::process() (in /bucket)
==24846==    by 0x408818: RedisCluster::HiredisCommand<RedisCluster::Cluster<redisContext, RedisCluster::DefaultContainer<redisContext> > >::Command(RedisCluster::Cluster<redisContext, RedisCluster::DefaultContainer<redisContext> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char const*, ...) (in /bucket)
==24846==    by 0x405104: get_key(char const*, redisReply*) (in /bucket)
==24846==    by 0x406013: main (in /bucket)
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I pass the reply pointer around, but I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Pass `reply` by address (pointer to pointer) to `get_key`.  Free it on the caller side. Or better still, pass a properly-sized key buffer to the `get_key` function and populate it, returning a success/failure state. That way you can just free the reply all within `get_key`. Right now `reply` back in the caller is unchanged, and you're code is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig ended up using a buffer, like I should have all along! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the first comment, you have a problem of indirection.

If I rewrite your code but inline `get_key` and rename the formal argument of `get_key` from `reply` to `replyLocal` and just concentrate on the `reply` variable we get

```
redisReply * reply;
//char * stats = get_key(key, reply);
{
// this is what happens in the function call, reply is copied in to replyLocal
char* replyLocal = reply;
// and this is in the body of the function
replyLocal = redisCommand(rc, "GET %s", key);
// if and return ignored
}
```

I hope that it is clear that the assignment to replyLocal **does not modify reply**. This means that when you try to free the memory it does not work as hoped.

If you change the signature of get_key to

```
char * get_key(const char* key, redisReply ** reply)
```

and adapt the body to the extra level of indirection, starting with

```
*reply = redisCommand(rc, "GET %s", key);
```

and the call then becomes

```
char * stats = get_key(key, &reply);
```

Applying the same sort of inlining as above we have

```
redisReply * reply;
//char * stats = get_key(key, &reply);
{
// this is what happens in the function call,
// ** the address of ** reply is copied in to replyLocal
char** replyLocal = &reply;
// and this is in the body of the function
*replyLocal = redisCommand(rc, "GET %s", key);
// if and return ignored
}
```

This now modifies what replyLocal points to so it also modifies reply

Comment: I ended up taking he advice of the comment on my question and just used an appropriately sized buffer to pass the result from redis around so I don't have to pass redisReply pointers around, but your answer was illuminating and helpful so I've accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not allocate memory for `redisReply *reply`, before calling the `get_key` function you must allocate memory.

Comment: oh I see, I assumed that was happening for some reason. Thanks! Do you have an idea of how I would do that?

Comment: I don't know if redis provides a function to allocate a memory, you need to check the documentation for that. In standard C you would use malloc.